How can I apply justified text alignment with RTL or LTR direction to a UITextView in iOS?
I want to apply justified text alignment to a UITextView and set the text direction to either RTL (Right-to-Left) or LTR (Left-to-Right). I'm working on a multilingual app and need to ensure that text is displayed correctly based on the language direction.
Here's what I have so far:

import UIKit

extension UITextView {
    
    func applyJustifiedStyle(_ direction: TextDirection) {
        guard let fontName = self.font?.fontName else {
            print("Font name is not set.")
            return
        }
        
        let fontSize = self.font?.pointSize ?? UIFont.systemFontSize
        
        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.alignment = .justified
        style.lineSpacing = fontSize / 1.5
        
        switch direction {
        case .LTR:
            style.baseWritingDirection = .leftToRight
            self.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
        case .RTL:
            style.baseWritingDirection = .rightToLeft
            self.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
        }
        
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .paragraphStyle: style,
            .baselineOffset: 0,
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.label, // Optional
            .font: UIFont(name: fontName, size: fontSize) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)
        ]
        
        if let text = self.text {
            let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)
            self.attributedText = attributedString
        }
    }
}



Usage :

textView.text = "some text"
textView.applyJustifiedStyle(.RTL)


However, I’m not sure if this is the best approach, or if there are any pitfalls I should be aware of. Can someone please provide insights or suggest improvements?
